# Asymmetric-Bipolar Pulsed-DC Magnetron Sputtering - Strontium Target

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Can a Strontium target be deposited on a substrate utilizing asymmetric-bipolar pulsed-dc magnetron sputtering?

Comment: Why would strontium not work in a sputter system?

Comment: I see on the Kurt J. Lesker site that its target datasheet references RF. I assumed pulsed-dc should work, but I am not a Process Engineer. I am curious what the different results are between 10 to 350 kHz versus 13.56 MHz?

Comment: Things like asymmetric-bipolar pulsed dc sputtering were developed mainly to help with deposition of things like oxide targets where charging is an issue. You just might not need the fancy option to deposit strontium (but might well for strontia).

Comment: My ultimate goal is to deposit Barium Strontium Titanate (BST) onto a Silicon substrate. Since this material is a dielectric ceramic, I should be able to use my pulsed-dc setup to deposit this material. The only question would be - should I use a BST target or three separate magnetrons with B, S and T targets to do the work?

Comment: Since B, S and T are each metals, would it be correct to assume that I could use standard DC sputtering in a three-magnetron setup?

Comment: If you want to vary the composition you will need to use three targets. As a compound target, the steady-state deposition will not match the original target composition because of differential sputter yields by mass. You will need to experiment. If you are sputtering in oxygen, you will make surface oxides, so the pulsed dc may be better. Looks like you have some experimenting to do, as well as reading the literature for what other folks have done.